# Munin does not show Apache/mySQL stats in web view

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apache-2.2, munin

I'm facing a very strange Problem. I just set up Munin on a fresh Ubuntu slice with a common LAMP Stack.

Everything works great, except that Munin does just not show the Apache/mySQL stats in the web view.

Everything else in the web view works great, Apache works, mySQL works. I even tried calling the plugins via console:

```
sudo munin-run apache_accesses
```

And it works fine. AFAIK Munin log files are not telling me any problems..

My only hint: when I run munin-run without sudo it gives me a "Permission denied" - could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. It worked all the time but Apache pointed to an old/non updated output of munin.